# Python PEP8 formatting for long arguments with annotations

Tags: python, lint, pep8

I have several function with log, annotated arguments such as the following:

```
def myfunction(values: Optional[List[str]],
               keywords: Dict[str, Tuple[str, int]],
               default_value: Optional[str]=None
               ) -> Dict[str, str]:
    ...
```

PEP8 doesn't say anything specifically about this, but the formatting above is my best estimate of what would be considered conventional. However, the linters suggest otherwise.  Flake8 is happy with this, and complains if I change it, pylint wants it formatted with a space at the default argument, and the brackets lining up:

```
def myfunction(values: Optional[List[str]],
               keywords: Dict[str, Tuple[str, int]],
               default_value: Optional[str] = None
              ) -> Dict[str, str]:
    ...
```

So flake8 and pylint contradict each other on the bracket indentation, and pylint insists on spacing around the `=` whichI'm pretty sure contradicts PEP8.

Is there any clear PEP8 guideline on this that I've missed? Or is it simply that pylint and flake8 have differing opinions on an undocumented case?  Regarding the `=` spacing, is pylint just plain wrong here, or is there some exception to PEP8 that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can usually format it like this to make pep8 and pylint happy (not that it's better though)

```
def myfunction(
    values: Optional[List[str]],
    keywords: Dict[str, Tuple[str, int]],
    default_value: Optional[str] = None
    ) -> Dict[str, str]:
```